# iptables rules missing after docker restart. How to save permanently?

Tags: docker, iptables

I am running docker and Zerotier and for Zerotier to work properly, I need to add rules to iptables. However, after each reboot this rule is removed by docker.

So I wanted to store the rule using iptables-persistent. But still, after reboot the rule is gone.
I was using

```
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p all -i br0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables-save
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Updated

When Docker starts it creates its own `iptables` rules. It creates `DOCKER-USER` chain for in `FORWARD`. It's suggested to put your rules there. The problem is than the rules disappear whenever you reboot system. Docker documentation doesn't give certain solution. My solution is:

The best solution I found is there:

https://michlstechblog.info/blog/linux-load-iptables-firewall-rules-at-startup/

On Debian/Ubuntu Linux the package is `iptables-persistent`.

If installed it loads at boot time the firewall rules from `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and `/etc/iptables/rules.v6`.

To generate those files, set your rules and save it with the helper scripts `iptables-save` and `ip6tables-save`.

IPv4 rules

1
root@debdev ~ # iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
IPv6 rules

1
root@debdev ~ # ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6
Enable daemon

1
root@debdev ~ #  systemctl enable netfilter-persistent.service

I put into `rules.v4` only the rules I want to add.
An example of `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` could be

```
*filter

# Reset counters
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]

# Flush
-F DOCKER-USER

# Filters :

# Block all external
-I DOCKER-USER -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
-I DOCKER-USER -d 192.168.1.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN

COMMIT
```

Other solutions:

1 - create script with rules `/root/bin/docker-iptables.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

while ! iptables -n --list DOCKER-USER >/dev/null 2>&1
  do
    sleep 1;
  done

  iptables -I DOCKER-USER -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
  iptables -I DOCKER-USER -d 192.168.1.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

2 - add the script to start at boot time
I chose `crontab`

```
crontab -l

# m   h    dom   mon   dow   command
@reboot                    /root/bin/docker-iptables.sh &
```

Also you may try this solution.

https://github.com/boTux-fr/systemd-service-iptables/tree/master

Answer (score -1):

`iptables-save` outputs the rules to stdout.  You need to write the output to the file the the system loads them from, typically `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`.

If you are root, this would work: `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

`sudo` of course doesn't play nice with redirects, but at least some `iptables-save` implementations (Ubuntu 20.04) has a `-f`/`--file` option that writes to a specified file under `sudo`:

`sudo iptables-save -f /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

Comment: [A comment posted as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74726559/5211833) here suggests that this doesn't work, because it resets all configurations.